# Plotting a line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a line graph along with points for a data set.
Unfortunately I am unable to plot the line in the graph, however, the points are plotted? 
I am getting the error as geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
can anyone help me out?

I have already made sure that all the variables are either numeric or character, and not factors. I also tried to label them as groups but it did not work.

```
df<- c('a','b','c','d','e')
df1<-1:5
df2<-11:15
df3<-21:25
df4<-cbind(df,df1,df2,df3)
colnames(df4)<-c("Names", "P1","P2","P3")
df4<-as.data.frame(df4)
dfplot <- gather(df4,key="Period", value="Price",-Names,P1,P2,P3 )
dfplot<-dfplot[order(dfplot$Names),]
vars<-c("Price")
vars1<-c("Names","Period")
dfplot[vars] <- sapply(dfplot[vars], as.numeric)
dfplot[vars1]<-sapply(dfplot[vars1], as.character)  

ggplot(dfplot, aes(x = Period, y = Price, color = Names),group=5 ) + geom_line()+geom_point()
```

Answer (score 0):

As your data is grouped, you need to tell the geom_line() which field the data is grouped on:

```
ggplot(dfplot, aes(x = Period, y = Price, color = Names),group=5 ) + geom_line(aes(group=Names))+geom_point()
```

[Some more information](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-line-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization#line-plot-with-multiple-groups)